# Get output of shell function used inside spec file

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

Hi I need to get the output (generated via `echo`) from a function inside a RPM spec file.

The function is

```
get_server_ip() {
        some staff
        echo $nodeip
        return 0
}
```

It is located in the file that I source:

```
source /usr/local/lib/script.sh
```

How can I get the value from the function inside script and use it as argument for `ssh-keygen`? I use GNU Bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command substitution to store the output printed by a command or function to `stdout` into a shell variable: Using

```bsh
my_value=$(get_server_ip)
```

in your script will store the string printed by `get_server_ip()` into the variable `my_value`, which you can then reference as usual using `"$my_value"` in the further script code.

If you are running this from an RPM spec file, be sure to define `bash` as a requirement using the appropriate `Requires` directive (see [here](https://rpm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rpm-guide.html) for example).

Comment: will the ssh-keygen some stuff -C name@$get_server_ip work?

Comment: It should work. However, be sure to write it correctly as `$( ... )`, and double-quote it as in `"$( ... )"` to prevent unwanted word splitting (which should not be an issue for IP addresses, but in general is a good idea to do).